# Faster ways to search points close to a line

Tags: algorithm, line, distance, point, nearest-neighbor

I have a set of points and a line in 2D space. I need to find all points that lie within a distance D from the line. Is there a way for me to do this without having to actually compute distances di of all points from the line? Is there a solution better than linear search?

Edit: I need to search through the same point set for different lines multiple times. The points are always constant but the line would be different during each search. Typically the point set is of the order of tens of thousands (~50k).

Comment: Are the points static? Do you need to do this only once or frequently? If you need to do this only once, I'm afraid that there is not any better solution.

Comment: The calculation is not very complex: [Wikipedia: Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

Comment: You may be able to save some time by looking for points for which the square of the distance from the line is less than D^2.

Comment: It sounds like this may be a query, in which you keep the same line but search multiple point sets or you keep the same point set and use different lines. The O(N) is the best you can do for the former while it seems like you could do O(k) or O(k log(N)) where k is the number of points returned, for the latter.

Comment: If there are a large number of points that are no where near the line, then you could use a rectangle that contains the oval that represents the space that is d from the line. It requires a bit of time to calculate, but any checking if a point is within that rectangle requires simply 8 comparisons, which may be cheaper than calculating the distance. Though you'd probably need at least millions if not billions of points for it to be worthwhile.

Comment: (1) One query only - i.e. only one set of points and one line? (2) For multiple queries, (a) does the line change? (b) do the points change? (c) does the distance change? (d) How often - every query or every x queries? (3) Do we know anything about the gradient of the line? Should we assume any gradient or can we assume a subset of gradients? (4) Is some degree of error acceptable?

Comment: @Dukeling: Same set of points and different lines. We can't assume a subset of gradients. Small probability of error might be acceptable.

Comment: @Nuclearman: Can you elaborate on the O(k)/O(klog(N)) solution?

Comment: Elaborated as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for queries:

If you create a kd-tree using the points, and use a few equidistant points (likely around d) points on the line, you should be able use a modifed nearest neighbor query to find all points that are withing d of a line in roughly O(k + log(N)). The kd-tree requires O(N log N) preprocessing through, so it's only better if you use the same point set (with perhaps slight differences as you can add/remove a point from a kd-tree in O(log N)) and different lines. The only issue is that a kd-tree isn't really meant for use with lines. I'm sure there is something like it for lines that would work better, but I'm not familiar with it.

Note: False positives and negatives are possible depending on how things are arranged, as you are really querying the distance from a point on the line instead of the distance on the line. How problematic this is largely depends on the ratio between the length of the line and d. Thus you are either going to get a fair number false positives or false negatives unless the majority of the points are no where near the line. In general, this probably won't be too much of an issue though, as even with the false positives k should be fairly small compared to N unless d is relatively large.

After a bit of review, I noticed that the query is against a line not line segment. It can however be converted into one by make the line segment bounded by the min/max x/y. I imagine there is still probably a more efficent way to use a kd-tree for this.

Answer (score 0):

This search can't be completed faster than linear search, as input data and result population has the same complexity.

Comment: For practical problems, constant multipliers can matter. I would generally rather run something that takes n nanoseconds than something that takes n minutes, even though both are O(n).

Comment: If there are 0 points in the output, the ideal query will take O(1), not O(n). You can't say the input and output have the same (space) complexity. For just about any algorithm with different size non-constant outputs, there are usually multiple variables involved when specifying complexity. For this particular example we can say there are `n` points in total and `m` points said distance from the line, with input being O(n) space and output O(m) space and the search taking O(f(m,n)).

Comment: @Dukeling: It's not clear this is a query question, although it probably is. So, given a line and a point set it doesn't seem like you can do better than O(N) without exceeding  O(N) in preprocessing.

Comment: @Dukeling, complexity can't be better than O(N), as you MUST check each point at least ones. e.g. complexity can't be better than read and output. Read complexity O(N), if you know how calculated complexity then for output it will be too O(N) complexity, not O(1) for special case.

Comment: I assumed multiple queries, for which each individual one can be as little as O(1), but, yes, there must be at least O(n) preprocessing. It's not clear whether or not this is the case from the question.